# RecyclerView .add() is working without calling .notifyDataSetChanged() after initializing adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my adapter why is `.add()` working even though I already set the adapter?

```
mFilePathImages = new ArrayList<>();
mGridAdapter = new HomeGridAdapter(mContext, mFilePathImages);    
mGridRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
mGridRecycler.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);

mFilePathImages.add("https://i.redd.it/lawrnev8v8o41.jpg");
mFilePathImages.add("https://i.imgur.com/GQXyo34.jpg");
```

Shouldn't it only work if I called `.notifyDataSetChanged`?

I checked my adapter to see if there was `.notifyDataSetChanged`, but there wasn't.

Here is the the full adapter for the Recycler:

````
public class HomeGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeGridAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "GridViewAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mList;


    public HomeGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vh_fraghome_griditem, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mList.get(i))
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                .into(holder.vhSquareImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.vh_fraghome_squareimageview)
        SquareImageView vhSquareImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Anyone know whats causing the issue

Comment: Does the adapter gets updated only when you scroll?

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan I'm not even scrolling. I only added two items to test the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that this is due to the fact that this code

```
mFilePathImages.add("https://i.redd.it/lawrnev8v8o41.jpg");
mFilePathImages.add("https://i.imgur.com/GQXyo34.jpg");
```

executes faster than the process of creating a view for recyclerView starts, so the call to notifyDataSetChanged is not required.Therefore, it works, but not the fact that it will work every time, so you should call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Isn't the code executed top to bottom? Why would that be faster

Comment: No, onBindViewHolder is executed as needed, so you can manage to add list items before the drawing process starts. I can be wrong, but I think this is the only option.

Comment: You can use the debugger and test my theory.

Comment: I just tried with adding 100 images after initializing the adapter and it still works so I doubt this is the cause

Comment: Try to run the code to add elements in a new thread before setting a delay of 2 seconds and report the result

Answer (score -1):

Java is always pass-by-value. Unfortunately, when we pass the value of an object, we are passing the reference to it, as you did it here :

```
 new HomeGridAdapter(mContext, mFilePathImages);
```

so now, whenever you change your mFilePathImages array, it will also effects the adapter.

For better clarification see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/9025616

for avoiding this situation you should pass array after you have final data(or any run-time changes). For adapter make list initially empty.

whenever you have your final data send it to your adapter as :

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list!= null) {
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```